# Probability that a randomly drawn subset of a randomly drawn subset has $k$ elements

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

> Let $A$ be a uniformly random subset of $\{1, 2, ... , n\}$. Let $B$ be a random subset of $A$, also chosen uniformly. What is the probability that $B$ has $k$ elements?

My approach was as follows:

Note that the probability of a subset of a size $N$ set having $m$ elements is $\frac{\binom Nm}{2^N}$, since there are $2^N$ possible subsets and $\binom Nm$ ways to make a subset with $m$ elements. Then

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Pr}(B \text{ has $k$}) &= \sum_j \operatorname{Pr}(B \text{ has $k$}, A \text{ has $j$}) \\
&= \sum_j \operatorname{Pr}(B \text{ has $k$}  \, | \, A \text{ has $j$}) \operatorname{Pr}(A \text{ has $j$}) \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^n \Big(\frac{\binom jk}{2^j}\Big)\Big(\frac{\binom nj}{2^n}\Big) \\
&= \frac 1{2^n} \sum_{j=0}^n \frac 1{2^j} \binom jk \binom nj
\end{align*}

But the summation $$\sum_{j=0}^n \frac 1{2^j} \binom jk \binom nj$$ [comes out to something nasty](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%202%5E-j%20*%20binom%28j%2Ck%29%20*%20binom%28n%2Cj%29%20from%20j%3D0%20to%20n), which makes me doubt my answer. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: [The sum should be from $j=k$ to $j=n$.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+2%5E-j+*+binom%28j%2Ck%29+*+binom%28n%2Cj%29+from+j%3Dk+to+n)

Comment: Another way to pose the question: First, flip $n$ fair coins. Then re-flip every coin that came up heads. What is the probability that $k$ heads come up at the end?

Comment: @angryavian Why does that matter? Isn’t $\binom jk$ zero for $k>j$? It seems to me that taking a sum from $j=0$ won’t allow contributions from these 0-probability events.

Comment: Computing that summation for individual values $k=0,1,2,\dots$ is something that WolframAlpha can do more nicely; it leads to the conjecture that the sum in question equals$$\frac{3^{n-k}}{2^n}\binom nk.$$

Comment: @GregMartin your conjecture is correct: see [Gould's Table of Combinatorial Identities vol. 2, page 4, (1.20)](https://web.archive.org/web/20171118024544/http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/Vol.2.PDF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Semiclassical mentioned in a comment, uniformly choosing a subset is equivalent to independently flipping a fair coin for each element to decide whether to include it in the subset. Thus, each element is included in the final result with probability $\frac14$, and the probability for $k$ elements to be included is given by the binomial distribution, $\binom nk\left(\frac14\right)^k\left(\frac 34\right)^{n-k}=\frac{3^{n-k}}{4^n}\binom nk$, in agreement with Greg Martin’s comment about the sum at the end of the question.